# How to sort a column (Y) for each group in column (X) in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

Is it possible to sort a column (Y) for each group in column (X) such that even values in column (Z) are changed?
I have about 23000 rows so manual sorting for each group is difficult.
I have attached the screenshot.

Picture showing the data layout for the problem:

[image]

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to grasp. You may want to include an example of how you would expect the output to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not asking for a VB script that does it every time you change a Z value, "Custom Sort" will do the trick.

Select the 3 columns, go to Sort > Custom List, located at Home tab and just add a level for X and a level for Y, value sorted.

[Microsoft Office Support - Sort data in a range or table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-ce451a63-478d-42ba-adba-b6ebd1b4fa24)